# MySQL error "empty string given as argument for ! character"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple query

```
select * 
from tablename 
where keyvar is not null 
order by keyvar
```

The query worked before but for some reason now I am getting an error:

> Error:Error formatting SQL query: empty string given as argument for ! character

Anyone has any idea why I am getting this error? Any help hugely appreciated

PS: If I run the whole code again from scratch (creating the database, loading the csv file etc) the query works fine.

Comment: [This came up when Googling "*empty string given as argument for*"](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/error-executing-query).

Comment: already checked it, I always google before asking... but it didn't work in my case :(

Comment: Is it in the MySQL workbench?

Comment: Yes, it is in the MySQL workbench 6.2. CE. And curiously enough, if I run the whole code again (creating the database, loading the csv file etc, the code works fine.

Comment: It sounds like it isn't actually using the database (the same problem that the link I gave you says). Instead of selecting the database (that you mentioned doesn't work), how about using `USE dbname;` before your query?

Comment: Maybe that's why, in the whole code I have the 'USE dbname;' code so that's why it works. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a necessary fix, though. (more of a hack) Are you sure that the database is marked with bold in the left panel?

Comment: In the navigator [schema tab] there is none of the schemas in bold. Even when I run the whole code and the query works.

Comment: On a fairly unrelated note, I use [**HeidiSQL**](http://www.heidisql.com/download.php) and have only been happy with it ever since I started. It's free just like MySQL Workbench is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, this is not a MySQL error - it's a MySQL Workbench error (you can see it in Oracle's source code [here](http://fossies.org/linux/mysql-workbench-community/library/base/sqlstring.cpp)).

Secondly, you'll get this error when no database is selected. There's two ways you can select one.

Let's look at what it looks like when *no* databases are selected:

[image]

as you can see it's not bold. This can be easily fixed by *double clicking* on the database name, or right clicking and choosing "*Set as Default Schema*":

[image]
[image]

Should you still not see any database selected on the left side, you can force it by using the SQL command [`USE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html) like so: `` USE `dbname`; `` (where `dbname` is your database name):

[image]