# Very simple MySQL SELECT statement causing error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Working out of an SQL book. (Using MySQL Workbench to run queries).

I'm running the following query

```
SELECT * FROM people;
```

Which produced the following error:

```
Error: Error formatting SQL query; empty string given as argument for ! character
```

---

I'm not sure what this error means.

For reference, a `DESC` of the `people` table is here:

```
Field               | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra

id                  |int(11)      |NO    |PRI  | NULL    | auto_increment
last_name           |varchar(50)  |YES   |     | NULL    |
first_name          |varchar(50)  |YES   |     | NULL    |
```

---

Comment: Could be a PEBKAC. "You have to double click on database name in the left panel to become bold."

Cfr https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/error-executing-query

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132697/mysql-error-empty-string-given-as-argument-for-character

Comment: The above query was prefaced by the appropriate `USE` command, but I guess the schema selection got lost somewhere along the way. Why did the `DESC` command still work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't selecte a database

Comment: The above query was prefaced by the appropriate `USE` command.

Comment: Try select it by double click

Answer (score 0):

You have to double click on the database in the left panel so that it becomes bold.